# Apache Virtual host warning: NameVirtualHost *:8081 has no VirtualHosts

Tags: php, apache, apache2, virtualhost

I am facing a apache warning in 1 of the Ubuntu machines as shown below..  after apache2 restart

Apache version is 2.2.22

```
 [warn] NameVirtualHost *:8081 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting .[warn] NameVirtualHost *:8081 has no VirtualHosts
```

I face above problem after configuring in vi /etc/apache2/ports.conf but this work with out any issue in other machines.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:8081
Listen 8081
```

I have a included virtual 8081 host in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file also

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
....
....
</VirtualHost>
```

what is causing the problem particularly in only 1 server bec in my local server it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow default file of Apache was not having a symbolic link to sites-enabled.
Path is mentioned below for reference.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default was not pointing to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.
```

Hence created a symbolic link and it works fine :)